# How to get bean from ServletContextListener in contextDestroyed

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I want to get bean in contextDestroyed so I have this code.

```
public class MyContextListener implements ApplicationContextAware, ServletContextListener {

    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(getClass());

    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        logger.warn("Start");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        logger.warn("End" + appContext);
        appContext.getBean("myBean")
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.appContext = applicationContext;
    }

}
```

problem is that it log `null`. But when I change it to

```
    private static ApplicationContext appContext;
```

then I can see my appContext. Why ? What is right options to get bean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 instances of the `MyContextListener`. One configured by Spring and one from the web container.

The one configured by Spring will have the `ApplicationContextAware` callback and have the `appContext` property set, but it isn't known to your servlet container and as such will not participate in the lifecycle callbacks.

The second instance is the one in your servlet container, however as that isn't a spring managed one it will not receive the callback for the `ApplicationContextAware` and as such the `appContext` is going to be `null`.

Making it `static` kind of "solves" it as it is now a class variable instead of an instance variable. Now all instances share that variable.

It is better to remove the `ApplicationContextAware` and use the `WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext` method in your listener instead.

```
public class MyContextListener extends BaseTask implements ServletContextListener {

    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        logger.warn("Start");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        logger.warn("End" + appContext);
        WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(event.getServletContext()).getBean("myBean");
    }

}
```

Now you only need the instance for the servlet container (web.xml or other means of configuring it) and you can remove the spring managed instance.